# increase size of excerpt in shopify

Tags: php, content-management-system, shopify

i am displaying blog articles in some text and at the end Read more button in order to view complete article in my shopify web

this is the code that i am using

```
<div class="rte">
  {% if article.image %}
    {% assign image_alt = article.title | escape %}
    <p>{{ article | img_url: '1024x1024' | img_tag: image_alt, 'article__image' | link_to: article.url }}</p>
  {% endif %}
  {% if article.excerpt.size > 0 %}
    {{ article.excerpt }}
  {% else %}
    <p>{{ article.content | strip_html | truncatewords: 100 }}</p>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

it worked very well now i set only one article to display

```
{% paginate blog.articles by 1 %}
```

it displayed only one article. 
i just want to increase the short description text of article to 50% with read more button.

is this possible to increase the size of article.excerpt so that i will display more text with read more button

i tried this but this is not work for me

```
{{ article.excerpt.size = 1200 }}
```

Comment: `{{ article.content | strip_html | truncatewords: 100 }}` changing *truncatewords* value doesn't work?

Comment: this worked for me but somehow it display all text without line breaks . i mean it display all text in a single paragraph

Comment: `strip_html` removes every html element in `article.content`

Comment: is there any other way in your experience to show article content 50% with html

Comment: `{{ article.content | truncatewords: 100 }}` use this. But make sure no the html tags don't get messed up while displaying.